# Were there any Catwomen who were not Selina Kyle behind the mask?

Tags: dc, batman, catwoman

In any of the **DC comic canon** (excluding movies), was Catwoman always Selina Kyle behind the mask?

I'm excluding things that happen in alternate times (e.g. future Terry McGinnis's Batman may possibly have had a different woman posing Catwoman - I didn't watch Batman Beyond to know if one existed - if she did, she wouldn't count).

Any continuity is OK from first Batman comics to New52.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, [Holly Robinson](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Holly_Robinson_%28New_Earth%29) took over as Catwoman for a while when Selina retired (temporarily), starting in Catwoman Vol. 3 #53.

(Just for the record, Terry McGinnis did face his own version of [Catwoman](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Catwoman_III_%28New_Earth%29), who was unrelated to Selina Kyle except for taking inspiration from her legend.)

Comment: I loved her in 21 Jump Street

Comment: @Kevin, wrong [Holly Robinson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0005372/). :-)